# How to cope with optional but unique keys in Akka?

Tags: akka

I have `UserActor` with a state which may or may not contain `email`.
 Each user is identified by a synthetic `UUID` - this id is used as actor's name.

What I'd like to achieve is to consistently prevent creation of multiple actors with the same email address.

The only idea I have so far is an implementation of cluster singleton actor for indexing created users by email. But then it becomes the single point of contention.

Comment: Can you provide the class/constructor signature for `UserActor`?  It is unclear how `email` & `name` are combined to make a UserActor...

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil Nothing special. It just processes the message `case CreateUser(id, userData, source)`. And `userData` is just a case class with `email` and other user properties.